# How to prove this delta-epsilon proof?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 9} \sqrt{x} = 3$$

This means we need to satisfy $|\sqrt{x} - 3| < \epsilon$ where $0 < |x - 9| < \delta$

But I don't really know how to make the two conditions match so we can link delta and epsilon together. Absolute values mess with my head and I don't know the right way to work with them.

Do I need to do something like:

$0 < |x - 9| < \delta$ turns to

$0 < |(\sqrt{x} + 3)(\sqrt{x} - 3)| < \delta$

$0 < |\sqrt{x} + 3| |\sqrt{x} - 3| < \delta$

$0 < (\sqrt{x} + 3) |\sqrt{x} - 3| < \delta$

$0 < |\sqrt{x} - 3| < \frac{\delta }{\sqrt{x} + 3} $

Comment: Here's a way to think about it. Let us say we are $\epsilon$ away from $3$. How close does $x$ need to be $9$ to get us that close?

Comment: @rubikscube09 Yes but that is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: Pretty close: now use the fact that $\sqrt  x \ge 0$ to find that $|\sqrt x - 3| < \frac{\delta}{3}$.  How should you choose $\delta$ to make sure the last expression does not exceed $\epsilon$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Did I make a mistake somewhere? I have that $0 < |\sqrt{x} - 3| < \frac{\delta }{\sqrt{x} + 3}$

Comment: Oh wait I could say $0 < |\sqrt{x} - 3| < \frac{\delta }{\sqrt{x} + 3} \leq \frac{\delta }{3}$ since $\sqrt{x} \geq 0$ right? Meaning $0 < |\sqrt{x} - 3| < \frac{\delta }{3}$.Then I can just pick $\delta = 3\epsilon$ and the $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ condition will be satisfied?

Comment: That is exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|x-9|<\delta\implies |\sqrt x-3||\sqrt x+3|<\delta\implies |\sqrt x-3|<\frac{\delta}{|\sqrt x+3|}=\frac{\delta}{\sqrt x+3}\le\frac{\delta}{3}=\epsilon$$ then letting $\delta=3\epsilon$ leads us to what we want.

Answer (score 0):

By your work.

Let $\delta=3\epsilon$.

Thus, $|x-9|<3\epsilon$ gives, which you wish:
$$|\sqrt{x}-3|<\frac{3\epsilon}{\sqrt{x}+3}\leq\epsilon.$$