# How to prove this delta-epsilon proof involving $x^2$?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

Unlike my [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2618123/70349) I want to try something where $x$ can be any real value in $f(x)$ so it's not just $x \geq 0$. I want to fix an $\epsilon$ and find the largest $\delta$ I can get away with using to make the necessary inequalities hold.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} x^2= 4$$

Say I pick some $\epsilon = 0.5$ which means I need to find some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ satisfying $0 < |x-2| < \delta$, the inequality $|f(x) - L| = |x^2 - 4| < 0.5$ holds.

1. Am I stating this correctly so far / understanding the delta-epsilon relationship and goals?
2. How do I pick the right $\delta$ for something like this?

Trying to simplify:

$|x^2 - 4| < 0.5$

$|x+2||x-2| < 0.5$

$|x-2| < \frac{0.5}{|x+2|}$

Now I'm stuck. Is there a better way to approach these problems? So far I've been trying to manipulate the epsilon inequality so it looks more like the delta one and then try to set the delta and epsilon expressions equal to each other, but maybe there is a more reliable way to prove these relationships?

Update:

Trying another way:

$|x^2 - 4| < 0.5$ simplifies to

$\sqrt{3.5} < x < \sqrt{4.5}$

This gives me two $x$-values away from $a=2$, either $2 - \sqrt{3.5} = .1291...$ or $\sqrt{4.5} - 2 = .1213...$

So if I pick the smallest of the two, $\delta = \sqrt{4.5} - 2$ which satisfies the epsilon condition?

Comment: Choose $\delta=\epsilon/5$ for $\epsilon<1$

Comment: "Am I stating this correctly so far / understanding the delta-epsilon relationship and goals?"  For the most part.  But there are two considerations you are eliding. i)$\epsilon$ doesn't have to be $.5$ but could be $.05$ or $.000000005$  of $5\times 10^{534}$.  It can be *any* value.  ii) And $\delta$ ... well it's best not to think of delta as a constant, but as a number whose value is *determined* by the value of $\epsilon$.

Comment: If $\epsilon = .5$ then just let $\delta$ be something really really small.  If $\delta = .01$ then $|x - 2| < \delta$ means $1.99 < x < 2.01$ so $3.9601< x^2 < 4.0401$ so $-.0399< x^2 - 4 <.0401$ so $|x^2 - 4| < .05 < .5$.  So.... that doesn't tell you much about how to do it in general.  Does it?

Comment: @fleablood I tried using a graph instead and edited my post. Does this approach make sense?

Comment: I understand $\epsilon$ can be any positive value, I'm just picking one arbitrarily, fixing some $\epsilon$, and then finding the largest $\delta$ that makes $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ hold. We could pick something very small and it would work but that doesn't show how large we could get away with going.

Comment: You're really not getting the point that $\epsilon$ can be *anything* and that $\delta$ has to be something expressed in terms of $\epsilon$.  If you just randomly pick values.  You'll never end.  For $\epsilon = 5\times 10^{-534}$ you might fine $\delta = 2.78\times 10^{-792}$ will work.  But you need so say that for *any* $\epsilon$ a $\delta = $ something determined by *that* $\epsilon$ will work.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but that isn't what I am trying to do at the moment

Comment: Well, *start* trying to do it at the moment.  Picking some numerical constant to be $\epsilon$ and some numerical constant to $\delta$ will not tell you how to do it for *any* $\epsilon$.  Picking *arbitrary* $\epsilon$s is BAD.  Don't do it.... (Okay that was overstating it a bit as it can give you insight maybe, but it is not the way to do it.)

Comment: @fleablood Sometimes it helps to do a concrete example before moving to an abstract one in order to see that it makes sense. You might do things differently and that's ok, but it's a far cry to say it's "bad" to do this. As a result of doing this example I now understand the general case so it's a helpful way to go sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show that $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists\delta>0$ such that

$$\forall x\neq2 \quad |x-2|<\delta \implies\left|f\left(x\right)-l\right|<\varepsilon$$

that is

$$|x^2-4|<\epsilon\iff-\epsilon<x^2-4<\epsilon\iff4-\epsilon<x^2<4+\epsilon\iff \sqrt{4-\epsilon}<x<\sqrt{4+\epsilon}\iff \sqrt{4-\epsilon}-2<x-2<\sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2\\\iff |x-2|<min\{\sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2,2-\sqrt{4-\epsilon}\}=\sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2=\delta \quad \square$$

Comment: I think your result is the same as mine correct? $\delta = \sqrt{4.5} - 2$? (I picked $\epsilon = 0.5$)

Comment: @ArukaJ Yes but you need to prove it in general for genrec $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ values.

Comment: For the *third* time.  !!!STOP!!! picking specific values of $\epsilon$.  It will *NOT* help you.

Comment: @fleablood do you agree with my proof?

Comment: @gimusi Oh, yeah.  Absolutely.  Looks good.  i haven't gone through it with a fine tooth comb but, yeah, that's exactly how do it. So barring any arithmetic errors, It's good.  My comment was for Aruka who seems hell bent on finding specific deltas for specific elements and not actually trying to find a *general* formula for deltas for *all possible* epsilons.

Comment: @fleablood I think one can take some numerical value for example and to better understand the algebra, but I agree with you, for the proof a generalization is needed.

Comment: Okay, one nitpick.  We should specify that as $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small we may assume $\epsilon < 4$.  But that's pretty trivial.

Comment: I chose a numeric value and used a graph to learn what is going on with epsilon delta proofs. I don't know why you have such a strong aversion to this @fleablood, using concrete examples is often a good way to learn tough or abstract concepts.

Comment: Well, it's fine to get an insight but there comes a point where you will have to say, insight is done, *now* we must do a proof.  And you will *NEVER* be allowed to say "It worked for all examples I tried therefore it must be true" as a proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$|x^{ 2 }-4|=\left| x-2 \right| \left| x-2+4 \right| <{ \left| x-2 \right|  }^{ 2 }+4\left| x-2 \right| $$

Answer (score 1):

If $|x- 2| < \delta$ then

$- \delta < x -2 < \delta$

$2 - \delta < x < 2 + \delta$.  Let's assume *for the moment* that $\delta < 2$.

$(2- \delta)^2 < x^2 < (2+ \delta)^2$

$4 - 4\delta + \delta^2 < x^2 < 4 + 4\delta + \delta^2$

$-4\delta + \delta^2 < x^2 - 4 < 4\delta + \delta^2$.

$-4 \delta - \delta^2 < x^2 - 4 < 4\delta + \delta^2$

$|x^2 - 4| < |4\delta + \delta^2| = 4\delta + \delta^2$ (because $\delta$ is positive)

So we want $\epsilon \ge 4\delta + \delta^2$.  Given that we know what $\epsilon$ is, can we find a way of figuring out $\delta$ *in terms of $\epsilon$* so that that would be true?

If we assume $\delta \le 1$ then $\delta^2 \le \delta$ so $5\delta \ge 4\delta + \delta^2$.

So if we choose any $\delta$ so that i) $\delta < 2$ and ii) $\delta \le 1$ and iii) $5\delta < \epsilon$ that will do.

So for any $\delta < \min (\frac \epsilon 5, 1)$ that will do.

So to do the proof:

For any $\epsilon > 0$, let $\delta = \min (\frac \epsilon 5, 1)$

Then if $|x - 2| < \delta$ implies by all the work we did above that

$-5\delta \le -4\delta -\delta^2 < -4\delta + \delta^2 < x^2 -4 < 4\delta + \delta^2 \le 5\delta$ so

$|x^2 - 4| < 5\delta \le \epsilon$.

And that's the proof.

Answer (score 0):

It is my honest opinion that your question lies in the realm of questions of the type: "what is the best approach for riding a bicycle?" - Most answers you will receive will send you snapshots of happy riders; but you don't really want these answers, do you? I suggest you get on the bike, and keep falling until you don't.

Comment: Are delta-epsilon proofs more art than science, is that sort of what you are saying? There is no standard methodical way to get the answer?

Comment: Is bicycle riding an art? No, it is a skill. delta-epsilon proofs are a skill. There are many skills that you can only pick up by actually doing. Swimming, bike-riding are two out of three immediate examples that come to mind.

Comment: Proofs in general are like this. There are some approaches that work more often than others, but it's more about the intuition of what works than following a particular step-by-step approach. In this case, the best advice you can get is to poke around with the triangle inequality and when you get something that works, try to understand what made it work.